# In todos example

Tags: javascript, meteor

In the "todos" example of meteor. There are 2/3 lines of code I don't understand. In the todos.js file:

```
Template.todo_item.tag_objs = function () {
   var todo_id = this._id;
   return _.map(this.tags || [], function (tag) {
     return {todo_id: todo_id, tag: tag};
  });
};
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tag_objs helper returns an array of tags in order to display them correctly in the  todo_item template.
They could have returned "this.tags || []", which means "return the tags array of this todo item if any, or else return an empty array".
If you return directly a raw array of data, you have to loop through it in the template using this syntax :

```
{{#each tag_objs}}
    {{this}}
{{/each}}
```

The this keyword will refer to the current tag being iterated over, but it's not that obvious and from a code clarity perspective, developers sometimes prefer to have a dedicated named helper.
So basically that's what is being accomplished in the helper definition : we underscore.map (http://underscorejs.org/#map) each tag value to a newly constructed object with proper "todo_id" and "tag" properties that we will be able to reference in the template code, so instead of {{this}} we can now use {{tag}}.

_.map simply transforms ["tag1","tag2","tag3"] into

```
[{
    todo_id:"ID",
    tag:"tag1"
},{
    todo_id:"ID",
    tag:"tag2"
},{
    todo_id:"ID",
    tag:"tag3"
}]
```